# Instruments CoreData doesn't seems to work even with simulator

Tags: ios, core-data

There is no data showing in Instruments tool, I tried it on every simulator and devices, but with no success. (I've even tried it on Xcode 8.0 8.3 and 9.0) Does anybody know what's happened with them and maybe there is some substitution?

Comment: It seems to work for me. Can you post a simple example project that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: i meant there is no data according to fetches count , fetches duration etc. Core Data tool itself is work, but it useless because it does not show me no info about fetches.